# At terminal velocity, acting upon a still object, would the impact of an impact-grenade cause more or less force than the explosion?

Tags: forces

This sounds absolutely moronic, I know. Especially after looking at most of the other questions on here, but this is the only place I can get, even, a somewhat realistic answer.

In detail, let's pretend my antagonist has dropped an impact-grenade because he's too cocky to use the launcher from his space ship just under the atmosphere.

If the grenade has reached terminal velocity and lands **EXACTLY** in the center of the protagonist's head, would the impact of the grenade hurt him more than the explosion would have, if it landed immediately next to him?

Also, would the explosion go off before he could feel the impact, perhaps?

Comment: This would need more precise phrasing in terms of physical concepts. "Hurt" (and its inorganic counterpart, "damage") is very vague, and "force" is tricky to apply to explosions. A reasonable question to ask from a physics point of view that would seem most germane to one's intuitive understanding of this situation would be to ask to compare the _energy_ delivered to the target in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object has a kinetic energy equivalent to its own mass' worth of TNT when it is moving at ~3 km/s. That is much higher than any terminal velocity, so unless the grenade contains very little explosive and/or a very weak one, the explosion will deliver much more energy than the impact.